# Why will integration by parts not work with this formula?

Tags: calculus, integration

Grateful for any help on this elementary problem

I'm trying to integrate

x+3/(x-2)^2

By parts. I get

(x+3)*-(x-2)^-1 + ln(x-2)

But this is incorrect, as can be verified by partial fractions. Also by switching the integration variables u and v you get a different, but correct answer. I can't see why doing it this way leads to an issue!

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: To know where you've gone wrong, it would be helpful to see the steps you tried.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest you take the time to learn the basics of [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Some users won't even read your question (let alone help you) if it's not properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're nearly correct. It's true that

$$ \int \frac{x+3}{(x-2)^2}\, dx = -\frac{x+3}{x-2} + \ln|x-2| + C $$

You need the absolute value in case $x<2$. (We can't integrate over an interval which includes $x=2$, but we could integrate in a domain either below or above the value $2$.) And of course there's the $+C$, which is always important in the solutions for an indefinite integral.

Probably the answer you considered "correct" was more like

$$ \int \frac{x+3}{(x-2)^2}\, dx = \ln|x-2| - \frac{5}{x-2} + C $$

which is also correct.

The constant $C$ can be any real number in each formula. To see if these solutions are really the same, let's try subtracting the answers, but using $C=C_1$ in the first formula and $C=C_2$ in the second.

$$ \left(-\frac{x+3}{x-2} + \ln|x-2| + C_1\right) - \left(\ln|x-2| - \frac{5}{x-2} + C_2\right) = \frac{-(x+3)+5}{x-2} + C_1 - C_2 = -1 + C_1 - C_2 $$

The difference is a constant, so both formulae describe the same *family* of functions when an arbitrary constant can be added. The single functions we would get if we ignore the $+C$ constant are different, but the solution to an indefinite integral is really the family of antiderivatives, not a single function.